# How to use pscp and putty same time, with one password?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

I have same password with pscp as putty (obviously) to an Ubuntu 13.04 server, and Im running a batch file, win 8.1 preview.
This batch file requires me to run 2 windows, and enter 2 passwords (PUTTY/PSCP). Is there any way
of telling putty, or PSCP, password is already entered, or, if you can combine these;
or alternate solution....

Thanks // Marcus.

Comment: Use keys and pageant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using ssh certificate keys means you wont need to enter your password interactively at all

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys

1) create the key pair
2) put pub key in .ssh/authorized_keys
3) use private key on the client to connect to server